# Why are my RenderingHints keys, when applied to a Graphics2D object, not being honored?

Tags: java, graphics

When drawing various things using a Graphics2D object and BasicStroke at 1.0f, I can't seem to get the g2d object to honor my RenderingHints settings. Specifically the *KEY_ANTIALIASING* set to *VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON*.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
    );

    // draw stuff...
}
```

Are there other keys I should be using? Am I not applying the keys in the appropriate place? Using it the way described above results in normal, pixelated shapes being drawn.

Answer (score 1):

If you are stroking (as it looks like you are from your snippet), you might want to also try:

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
```

Comment: When I try and use the stroke control key, I still get no effect. It is still pixelated (no anti-aliasing). Any other suggestions?

Comment: In a JPanel with g2d.drawOval( 10, 10, 300, 300 ); w/o your hints looks bad.  W/ your hints, looks good.  What type of object are you drawing into?  What are you drawing?

Comment: I'm drawing directly into a JFrame, would that have a significant impact on this? It seems Graphics2D should be the same anywhere you attempt to use it. Is it limited when used in this particular context?

Comment: Just grasping at straws here, thought maybe you were painting into something funky (an SVG or PDF context). I tried extending a JFrame using your overridden paint method to g2d.drawOval( 10, 10, 300, 300 ); and it looks smooth.  Sorry!  If I think of something, I'll post.